# SSO authentication against active directory using sourceforge spnego

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, servlet-filters, spnego

I have implemented SSO authentication using the [sourceforge spnego project](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/).

This is my first time implementing any kind of servlet authentication so I may be missing something very basic with authentication or servlets that I just don't know about...

I am using the `SpnegoHttpFilter` that comes packaged with the library at the top of my filter chain with no overrides, then I included my own filter `QueryFilter` next in the filter chain so that I can map the logon name to the database user_id. The logon name (NT User ID on windows domains) is returned by a `getRemoteUser` call after the HttpRequest passes through the `SpnegoHttpFilter`, this all seems to be working fine.

My own filter `QueryFilter` is doing what it is supposed to do, it is mapping the logon name to the database user_id correctly. I also have logic in this filter to reject requests that don't pass my authentication, this is working fine also: when I simulate an unauthorized request this filter stops it and it never makes it to the servlet.

The trouble is that *all* requests return as 401 (HTTP Request Status Unauthorized) even when they pass authentication in my `QueryFilter` and execute totally fine on the servlet.

I tried explicitly defining the response as 200 (HTTP Request Status OK) in my own filter using this: `myHttpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)` but that didn't change anything.

To isolate the problem I removed the `HttpSpnegoFilter` altogether and just passed a hard-coded logon name (NT User ID) to my `QueryFilter`. This worked fine and the responses were no longer 401 (Unauthorized).

That means the packaged `HttpSpnegoFilter` is somehow converting the request to `Unauthorized`. And doing it in a way that it doesn't change when I say it is actually OK.

Does anyone know how I can set the response header to return as 200 (OK) using this spnego sourceforge project?

My full filter chain from the web-app's `web.xml` is below, as mentioned I use the packaged `HttpSpnegoFilter` at the top of the chain and then my own filter (which seems to be doing it's job correctly) right below it:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.delegation</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.localhost</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.unsecure.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.client.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-client</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.krb5.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>krb5.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>login.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.username</param-name>
        <param-value>myADServicePrincipal</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.password</param-name>
        <param-value>myADServicePrincipalPassword</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.server.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-server</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.prompt.ntlm</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.logger.level</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>QueryServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>QueryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.package.name.QueryFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>query.permission.list</param-name>
        <param-value>getQueryPermission</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>remote.user.column</param-name>
        <param-value>nt_user_id</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>user.id.column</param-name>
        <param-value>user_id</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>QueryFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>QueryServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also included my `QueryFilter` for completeness below (Even though it doesn't seem to have any bearing on my problem because it works fine by itself when I don't use the `SpnegoHttpFilter` class and just pass it a hard coded NT User ID). The second to last line is where I explicitly tell the response to be `OK` to no avail:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public final class QueryFilter implements Filter {

    private MapListDAO myMapListDAO;
    private String myPermissionsList;
    private String myRemoteUserColumn;
    private String myUserIdColumn;


    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        myMapListDAO = Config.getInstance(filterConfig.getServletContext()).getMapListDAO();
        myPermissionsList = filterConfig.getInitParameter("query.permission.list");
        myRemoteUserColumn = filterConfig.getInitParameter("remote.user.column");
        myUserIdColumn = filterConfig.getInitParameter("user.id.column");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO ...?
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String queryName = request.getParameter("queryName");
        // because I have SpnegoHttpFilter earlier in my filter chain
        // this returns the NT User ID (what the user logged in to the domain with)
        String remoteUser = httpRequest.getRemoteUser();
        Map<String, Object> queryPermissions = myMapListDAO.getEntry(myPermissionsList, myRemoteUserColumn, remoteUser);

        // if there is no queryName defined
        if (null == queryName) {
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, 
                    "Missing queryName parameter.");
            return;
        }

        // if this query is protected perform the gauntlet
        if (myMapListDAO.getList(myPermissionsList).get(0).containsKey(queryName)) {

            // if there is no remoteUser
            if (null == remoteUser || remoteUser.isEmpty()) {
                httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, 
                        "Cannot get remoteUser.");
                return;
            }

            // if the remoteUser does not have any queryPermissions
            if (null == queryPermissions) {
                httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, 
                        "Cannot find queryPermissions for " + remoteUser + ".");
                return;
            }

            // if this remoteUser does not have permission to execute the queryName
            if ((Boolean) queryPermissions.get(queryName)) {
                httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, 
                        "The remoteUser: " + remoteUser + " does not have permission to access queryName: " + queryName + ".");
                return;
            }

        }

        // attempt to add the userId to this request as an attribute we can get later
        if (null != queryPermissions) {
            httpRequest.setAttribute("userId", String.valueOf(queryPermissions.get(myUserIdColumn)));
        }

        // continue to servlet
        httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}

    // attempt to add the userId to this request as an attribute we can get later
    if (null != queryPermissions) {
        httpRequest.setAttribute("userId", String.valueOf(queryPermissions.get(myUserIdColumn)));
    }

    // continue to servlet
    httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because my app is wholly intranet based I ended up dropping security protocols altogether.

I simply created a database table with all of my domain ip-addresses and a column for the current user ID, logon time and logoff time.

I wrote some server side code to update this table whenever a user logs on or logs off of active directory.

Now, because we can get the remote address pretty easy, I wrote a servlet filter that:

1. checks if their is an HttpSession attribute for the user ID
2. if not, queries the database for the user ID and stores it in a session attribute
3. performs some custom authentication based on the user ID and either rejects or passes the request
4. if the request passed the filter sends my servlet a wrapped HttpRequest that forces `getRemoteUser` call to return my user ID session attribute.

I suppose it would be possible for a user on the intranet to change their IP address to copy someone else, but when I tried I just got errors that a duplicate IP address existed and I wasn't able to connect to anything on the intranet.

**Update (3 months later):**

I ended up going with [**waffle**](http://dblock.github.com/waffle/) in the end. It was very easy to integrate. My solution above was not workable for a number of reasons.